# Web API Authorization Filter not being hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have set of role-type claims that I've added to a user's identity on login. Now I need to create a scheme to authorize access to certain controllers based on these claims.

It seems from the documentation that this is best accomplished by creating a custom filter, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the filter to fire.

Here's what I've tried:

APPROACH 1 - Creating a ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute derived from System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute and overriding OnAuthorizationAsync (I've also tried overriding OnAuthorization), then registering the filter in WebApi.config.

APPROACH 2 - Creating a ClaimsAuthorization class derived from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and overriding IsAuthorized, also registering the filter in WebApi.config.

In both cases I've also tried adding a [ClaimsAuthorization] decoration to the controller method, also to no avail.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you set the debugger in ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute.cs, does it get hit?

Comment: That's correct. I've put a break on the overridden methods and they never get hit.

Comment: Ok, could u show the WebApiConfig.cs class

Comment: Could you please show the code of both `WebApiConfig.cs` and `ClaimsAuthorization`?

Comment: Hey Christok, your question is quite ambiguous - have you already assigned roles to the user when they authenticated? Or is that what you are trying to do? If you have successfully added roles to the principal, you can check for these roles using the standard `[Authorize("Role")]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be resolved by appreciating a subtle but important distinction: instead of deriving from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute I needed to use System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.

Unfortunately this exposes no OnAuthorizationAsync to override so I had to code around that to leverage my async methods.